# how to add threshhold value in the QnA maker if it being called using the QnAMakerRecognizer.recognize method

Tags: botframework, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I replaced my code where I was making a QnA dialog using new cognitiveservices.QnAMakerDialog constructor and I was able to pass extra key-value pair for example threshold, feedbackLib etc. with the code where I can use QnA in single dialog using

```
cognitiveservices.QnAMakerRecognizer.recognize(query, 'QnAhost', 'endpointKey key','Authorization', 3, 'intentname', function (error, results) 
        {
            session.send(results.answers[0].answer); 
           // console.log(results);
    }); 
}).triggerAction({
    matches: 'intentname'
});
```

But I am not sure how can I add the threshold value and feedbackLib to the QnA. This way it is returning an answer even if the confidence score is very low.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Vivek,
the constructor for QnAMakerRecognizer takes a set of IQnAMakerOptions. These are defined [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/Node/src/QnAMakerRecognizer.ts)

When you create your recognizer instance call the contructor like this:

```
var recognizer = new cognitiveservices.QnAMakerRecognizer({
      knowledgeBaseId: 'set your kbid here',
      authKey: 'set your authorization key here',
      qnaThreshold: (This is a number) set your threshold value here,
      feedbackLib: (This is a QnAMakerTool object) set your lib here
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to make a variable for the recognizer, instead, I am using the posted code inside the dialog itself. I will eventually have many QnA instances so I want to use the recognize method directly to avoid each time make a recognizer and then add it into the dialog.

Comment: I understand. The IQnaMakerOptions are passed in to the class via its constructor. Since you want to use a static method, you are not acting on an instance of a class but the class itself. The constructor is never called. If you are concerned about constructing the recognizer, are you aware that you can pass in a recognizer to the QnaMakerDialog constructor? You could create a single instance of the recognizer and use it with all of you dialog classes.